# ImageMap type repeating itself

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have posted an image map type in my site but the image repeats itself if you zoom in and zoom out image. The platform i am using is Joomla. Editor is JCE Editor.this is how it looks in my web http://logic.al/qtu2/index.php/maptest. What am i missing here ???

```
var moonTypeOptions = {
  getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      var normalizedCoord = getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom);
      if (!normalizedCoord) {
        return null;
      }
      var bound = Math.pow(2, zoom);
      return 'http://i.imgur.com/9iGCzkv.png' +
          '/' + zoom + '/' + normalizedCoord.x + '/' +
          (bound - normalizedCoord.y - 1) + '.png';
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1130, 604),
  maxZoom: 3,
  minZoom: 0,
  radius: 1738000,
  name: 'Moon'
};

var moonMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(moonTypeOptions);

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 5,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['moon']
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('moon', moonMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('moon');
}

// Normalizes the coords that tiles repeat across the x axis (horizontally)
// like the standard Google map tiles.
function getNormalizedCoord(coord, zoom) {
  var y = coord.y;
  var x = coord.x;

  // tile range in one direction range is dependent on zoom level
  // 0 = 1 tile, 1 = 2 tiles, 2 = 4 tiles, 3 = 8 tiles, etc
  var tileRange = 1 << zoom;

  // don't repeat across y-axis (vertically)
  if (y < 0 || y >= tileRange) {
    return null;
  }

  // repeat across x-axis
  if (x < 0 || x >= tileRange) {
    x = (x % tileRange + tileRange) % tileRange;
  }

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: The images you use as tiles are always the same

Comment: what should i use in this case?i wasnt able to find other layer map objects. i need to zoom the image only

Comment: There is no good approach with a single image. The image will be blurry when you zoom it

Comment: doesnt matter just wanna earn some time to learn action script and than change it completely. at the moment just wanna leave that imagemap  there